# How to block programs in windows 8 firewall correctly?

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-8

I am new to Windows 8, Generally using Ubuntu and/or OpenSuse, and Windows 7, My new laptop came with Windows 8 - 64bit.

Anyway normally in Windows 7 when I want to control access for specific program to the internet, I open Windows Firewall add some inbound/outbound rules, and it works perfectly.

But in Windows 8 I failed to do anything like that e.g. I have the old Google Talk app. Did the following:

1. Opened Windows Firewall
2. Create inbound rule > Program > `GoogleTalk.exe` > Block Connections > check all Private/Public/Domain > Added scope > Local IP: `0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255`
3. Saved -> Turned firewall off then on.
4. Closed Google Talk > then Opened again
5. Google Talk still works normally including sending/receiving files!

What did I miss or what am I doing wrong ?

I noticed something: Some programs are blocked, others are not, is it possible that the programs I blocked run other executables? for example in Linux when this happens, it's usually a sub-process, does Windows treat sub-processes similar to the main process ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking ***inbound*** connections, you need to block ***outbound*** connections. Inbound connections are connections that the other computer initiates (you act as a server), outbound connections are connections you initiate to other computer (you connecting to a server).

Comment: OMG: I know this, It was so stupid question :D, I totally forgot about outbound... thanks mate